# NSManagedObjectContext performBlockAndWait causing deadlock when called from two threads

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, core-data

I have an OSX app where I'm using a parent/child NSManagedObjectContext setup. The child MOC has `NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType` and is the one that I'm primarily using. The parent is set to be `NSMainQueueConcurrencyType`

When I call `performBlockAndWait` on the child context from a background thread at the same time as it is called from the main thread I get deadlock – `semaphore_wait_trap`. Pausing the debugger shows both threads are stuck at `performBlockAndWait`

How can I get around this? I thought this method was designed for exactly this situation and would simply queue up the blocks on the context's private queue then return appropriately?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I worked around this by creating a serial queue and then doing all my performBlock calls through this to make sure they wouldn't mess each-other up. Honestly, I'm not sure if this is good practice but it did solve the problem for my particular situation.

Answer (score 1):

NSManagedObjectContext's are still not thread safe, even with the private concurrency types.

performBlock: and performBlockAndWait: only ensure the block operations are executed on the queue specified for the context.

You can still get deadlocks with performBlockAndWait:, as it will block the currently executing thread until it returns. What is happening inside the performBlockAndWait:? Probably something that requires access to the main thread, which is why it is deadlocked.

Can you use performBlock: instead?

Comment: hmm i can try and switch over my code to performBlock yes, will definitely be a bit longer with the callbacks etc but totally possible I'm sure. So by using that method the blocks will be executed in a threadsafe manner?

Comment: performBlock and performBlockAndWait just ensure that the block you pass into them is executed on the correct queue associated with the managed object context. So yes, your blocks will be executed in a thread safe manner on the context - the difference is in the semantics of your code and if you need to block and wait for the block to complete. I'd always strive to use performBlock first and use performBlockAndWait if I had to for whatever reason. See http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#releasenotes/DataManagement/RN-CoreData/index.html